# Is "down the years" a common idiom?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

Is it possible to say that "something horrible will happen **down the years**"?

Comment: **2.** throughout, over, through, during *This domination has extended gradually down the years.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down It's not quite an idiom but a very common expression. The idiom is *down the road* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+the+road

Comment: No, not necessarily in the future. See the example: ***has extended** gradually down the years*.

Comment: It merely means '(during/) in the course of (a period)'.

Comment: I would say "something horrible will happen {over time / eventually / in the long run}".

Answer (score 2):

I think [down the years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down%20the%20years,%20Down%20the%20years&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,down%20the%20years;,c0;.t1;,Down%20the%20years;,c0), is mainly used to indicate a period in the past:

- I worked  a lot down the years.
- I used to travel  a lot down the years.

To refer to a period in the future I rather use the expression 'down the road'.

- Our project will hopefully be successful  down the road.